# compile a c++ SDL2 program using the gcc compiler on a mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compilation, sdl

I have experience compiling using the gcc compiler on mac, windows, and linux systems and know how to compile will dll's in windows. In this instance, I want to compile a SDL2 program using a mac with the gcc compiler (I have done it on a windows machine); however, when you download the development libraries off the site they do not include any shared library files, only header files. I am currently just a computer science student so I am not the best programmer, if you could help me out compiling a simple SDL2 program showing me all the command prompt options and flags that would be great!

P.S. I do not want to use Xcode to get the job done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First copy the SDL2.framework in the .dmg to your ~/Library/Frameworks.
Include the headers in your project `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`.

You can then compile it by using:

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, I was looking all over the internet for just that simple command! Much appreciated!

Comment: P.S. for anyone else who sees this post the 'gcc' needs to be "g++" for compiling c++ code

Comment: Just a note: `gcc` can/will be an alias for clang by default unless you've explicitly installed gcc via homebrew or ports.